Magento 2 Hosting and Domain
Please suggest me the service provider where I can get the domain and hosting for the Magento site. The customers will be on the site maximum 1k per month.
Suggest me cheap and good service.

You can go for shared hosting from either Fastcomet, Siteground or any other service provider, Just ask them and confirm if they support Magento.
If you want to try cloud hosting once then Try this https://shorturl.at/egjP9
I can't say the cheapest but its worth.
